# Show |x| is not differentiable at x=0 using delta epsilon

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

I need to show that the absolute value of x is not differentiable at x=0 using epsilon - delta. Thank you.

My thoughts: The absolute value at 0 is where we have a sharp cusp, so it's obviously not differentiable there because that's where the sided limits do not match.  In terms of epsilon-delta, we need an epsilon that creates an instance where delta cannot be true to pose a contradiction.  I assume that an epsilon of 1/2 would work nicely for this cause, but am unsure where to get the contradiction.  If we plug in 1/2 for epsilon, 0 for x, and 1 for the other variable, c, then we end up with 1<delta and 1/2<Derivative.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use limits, how can you use $\varepsilon-\delta$ in your proof?

Comment: @5xum Fair enough, I posted my thoughts and would really appreciate any feedback!

Comment: @AndrewChin I intended to convey that I was not allowed to use a defined limit such as lim(x->0+) in order to prove this.  But it has been edited for clarification.  Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, by definition of a derivative, for $\lvert x \rvert$ to be differentiable at $0$ the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\lvert x \rvert - \lvert 0 \rvert}{x - 0} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\lvert x \rvert}{x}$$ must exist. Now you can apply the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition to show this limit in fact doesn’t. Can you take it from here?

(If you need a hint at any point, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891822/proving-whether-a-limit-exists-at-a-point-piece-wise-function/3891861#3891861) for a full solution.)

P.S. The expression above may be written as $$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } 0<\lvert x - 0 \rvert<\delta \implies \left\lvert \frac{\lvert x \rvert}{x} - L\right\rvert < \varepsilon $$ using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ notation, where $L$ is the supposed limit. Please refer to my answer linked above for a detailed proof of why such $L$ could not exist.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot.  I do understand what you have written, but I am not supposed to use a limit such as that in this proof.  I am supposed to use solely delta and epsilon.  My main trouble occurs when trying to figure out where to draw a contradiction

Comment: @Altoid_10 What can you say about the value of $|x|/x$ when $x > 0$? And when $x < 0$?

Comment: @Bungo, When x>0, |x|/x=1.  When x<0, |x|/x =-1.

Comment: What I have written is just shorthand for the corresponding $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition: $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $0< \lvert x - 0 \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert \lvert x \rvert - L \lvert < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @Altoid_10 Yes. Now suppose you take $\epsilon < 1$. Is it possible to find a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $0 < |x| < \delta$, the values of $|x|/x$ are constrained to an interval of the form $(L - \epsilon, L+\epsilon)$?

Comment: @bungo I do not believe it is.  For the proof, should I pick an instance of epsilon or simply have it be less than 1?

Comment: @ChubbyChef, Thank you, I am just not used to seeing it written as such.

Comment: @Altoid_10 To prove that the limit does not exist, you just need a single example of an $\epsilon$ for which no $\delta$ can be found. So you can choose $\epsilon$ to be any specific number less than $1$, say $\epsilon = 1/2$ to be concrete.

Comment: @bungo.  Thank you, I tried the proof with 1/2.  I'm afraid I don't know how to use the formatting as I am too new, but I'll do my best.  The definition I was given was

for every epsilion that is a positive number, if c is in the domain of f and delta> |c-x|.  Then ( (f(c)-f(x)) / (c-x) )  + D < epsilon

If there is no relation between delta and epsilon, how can I draw a contradiction?

Comment: @Altoid_10 It's hard to tell, but I'm not sure the definition you cite is correct. I've updated my answer to provide additional clarification, so have a look and see if it's clear now.